# ghostscript compression distorts graphics

Tags: latex, ghostscript, inkscape

I am writing a large document in LaTeX and generate most of my schematics using Inkscape. I store all Inkscape schematics as PDF and include them using the default latex figure environment.

Because the final result is quite large I then compress the document using ghostscript, using the following bash command:

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -sOutputFile=${FNAME}_compressed.pdf $FNAME.pdf
```

$FNAME is the PDF file name. I noticed that the compressed PDF distorts some of the PDF graphics generated by Inkscape, mostly replacing solid black lines for dashed ones.

I uploaded a [distortion example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkfiS.png). The uncompressed original is on the right. Ghostscript distorted version on the left.

The distortion happens regardless of the dPDFSETTINGS flag. As far as I understand Ghostscript compression works by regenerating the PDF code so that it looks the same, but obviously this is not working correctly. However, the only images affected appear to be the Inkscape generated PDFs. Matplotlib generated ones appear to be fine.

Could you help me figure out, what is wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That looks like a bug. First question; what version of Ghostscript are you using ? If its old, upgrade and try again. If you get the same result, then submit it as a bug to bugs.ghostscript.com. Please note that the one hting you are not doing is 'compressing the document'. You are creating a brand new PDF file, the internals of which will be utterly different to the original. In this particular case you may also end up with images at different resolutions and other changes as well (because you selected -dPDFSETTINGS).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I realize that "compressing" means "rewriting" the PDF. The DPI of pictures is changed etc..

Comment: I use version 9.18, which is the newest version for Ubuntu. I will try 9.19 and let you know if that fixes things.

Comment: I doubt if it will, I can't think of anything which would have fixed that. If you do open a bug, please do remember to attach the original file :-)

Comment: The problem is not fixed with 9.19. 

I will open a bug report now. Thanks for the help. I will remember to add the original and new file.

Comment: For the benefit of anyone following this thread, this was a bug. See http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=697109